# Regex to match all capital and underscore in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I need to find all words from string which has only capital letter and underscore

```
string str = "ABCD_EFG_LMNO hello world PQR_ST_UVW  US Apple PQR__ZYZ PQR__LMN__ZYZ";
string pattern = "[A-Z_]+[_][A-Z]+";
```

Out put should be only below words

```
ABCD_EFG_LMNO 
PQR_ST_UVW
```

Comment: And your current output is...

Comment: Current OutPut is ABCD_EFG_LMNO PQR_ST_UVW PQR__ZYZ PQR__LMN__ZYZ

Comment: Should this substring be matched:  ABC__`DE_F`901_R  even if not a possible string ?

Answer (score 3):

When you use character classes, the order is ignored. Use groups instead:

```
[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)+
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/bU0rH9)

Comment: +1 At least this is shorter and it turned out that I had a small flaw :)

Comment: Thanks a lot its working, Could you please explain the pattern, especially  (?:_[A-Z]+)

Comment: @AnsariTanveer `_[A-Z]+` should be easy to understand. It's an underscore followed by any number of uppercase letters. Now, if you put this into `(?: ... )+`, this means that this group (`_[A-Z]+`) is being repeated through the quantifier `+` (meaning at least once).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
string strRegex = @"(?<base>[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)+))";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.Multiline);
string strTargetString = @"ABCD_EFG_LMNO hello world PQR_ST_UVW  US Apple PQR__ZYZ PQR__LMN__ZYZ""" + "\n\n\n";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    // Add some displaying code
  }
}
```

Tip: use [RegExHero for .NET](http://regexhero.net/) to try :)